# Confirm recursive instantiation will allow hierarchical object instantiation

Tags: fb-hydra

I'd like to be able to write a yaml file something like:

```
runner:
    _target_: my_module.Runner
    lightning_module:
        _target_: my_module.MyLightingModule
        precision: 16
    data_module:
        _target_: my_module.MyDataModule
        training_data: s3://foo/bar.csv
        validation_data: s3://foo/bar_val.csv
        test_data: s3://foo/bar_tst.csv
```

and then in my program run this whole thing by doing simply:

```
runner = hydra.utils.instantiate(cfg)
runner.run()
```

I see there is a PR to enable recursive instantiation, ie https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/pull/989 Please can you confirm that this will enable the code/config above?

Also, what is intended release date for this merged PR?

(I feel kind of a little bit non-standard putting questions which are basically feature requests into stackoverflow, so if you have a better suggestion on where to put these, please let me know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go ahead and check-out Hydra from master and play with the recursive instantiation support to confirm for yourself.

The docs for instantiate in the next version are [here](https://hydra.cc/docs/next/patterns/instantiate_objects/overview).

There is no set date for 1.1. but it will be a while.
At some point there will be some dev releases though. For now you can install from master.

Comment: installing from master doesn't fit well into pipeline. I think it mostly precludes it from use. by 'a while', do you mean more like weeks or months?

Comment: Months.
I recommend that you experiment with it to that that once it's released it will address your use case.